# Is there any reason this event function is not triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a set of jQuery objects pushed into a 'sections' Array. I add an .on event listener and I'm console.log-ing to check if the function is called, but it isn't.

```
sections.push($('#section' + p_sectionIndex));
sections[sections.length-1].on('show', this.showSection);

this.showSection = function() {
    console.log("Section should show");
}
```

Elsewhere in the code I call:

```
sections[showIndex].trigger('show');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All of the above code is in a Section function which I create as a new Section(...parameters...). So my best guess is 'this' points to the Section object. The showSection function is a function of the Section object, so it should fire, right? I'm not getting any errors. 'showIndex' is just a shorthand I'm using here to demonstrate how I'm triggering the function - but, I've checked that the value is within the bounds of the sections Array. Once again, I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `this.showSection` it is undefined because the [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_expression_.28function_operator.29) is not yet executed. So the handler is not registered

```
this.showSection = function () {
    console.log("Section should show");
}

sections.push($('#section' + p_sectionIndex));
sections[sections.length - 1].on('show', this.showSection);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pk2z6/)

But if you use [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_declaration_.28function_statement.29), it will get [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

```
jQuery(function () {
    function handler1() {
        console.log('handler1')
    }

    console.log('handler1', handler1)
    console.log('handler2', handler2)
    $('button').on('click', handler1).on('click', handler2)

    function handler2() {
        console.log('handler2')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8KmW/)

Comment: For now I'm going to stick with thinking that it wasn't working because the function was defined AFTER the .on was added. I'm not sure I fully get function-based scope yet. Surely functions can access variables outside themselves - The first section of code on the 'hoisted' link seems to suggest otherwise.